# Converting Text to CSV - Lined file

Tags: database, csv, text, alternating

I have a little difficulty with a problem at hand

I have a rather large database that was stored in a hellishly complex html format, but I've managed to convert it to a simpler, easier to use plain text format.

The format is now something along the lines of:

```
'Owner'  
FakeOwner  
'Thread'  
FakeOwner and FakeRespondant  
'Message'  
This is a short Message  
'Date'  
Tuesday, 28 January 2014 at 08:49 UTC+11
```

The issue then becomes to convert it to a useable format, preferably csv. The main difficulty is in the fact that for every line which has what would be a column in a database, I can't predict which order it will appear.

e.g.

```
'Owner'  
Andrew  
'Owner'  
Nathan  
'Thread'  
Andrew and Alex  
'Message'  
Fake Message
```

However, I can say that it will always alternate lines of column to value, as seen above. (Though some 'values' are only the end-of-line symbol. [\n, not \r\n]

Sample:
'Owner'
 Redacted name
'Thread'
 Redacted name, Redacted name
'User'
Redacted name
'Date'
 Tuesday, 28 January 2014 at 08:49 UTC+11
'Message'

'User'
Redacted name
'Date'
 Tuesday, 28 January 2014 at 08:50 UTC+11
'Message'
This is a message.

Comment: why don't you remove the string inside of the commas, doing this you are left only with data , knowing it's order just replace de /n  with your csv separator!

Comment: As I said "I can't predict in which order it will appear".

Comment: Do you have them in txt file ? can you post a sample of that data as it is inside the file ?

Comment: I can't post the entirety of the file, mostly because it's sensitive information, but I have tried a larger example of what is in the file.

Comment: @Up_One the file has the following headers: (Owner, Thread, User, Date, Message, Download Date), but they occur in differing orders, e.g. Several Messages may occur under a single thread title, so the Thread section isn't repeated.

Comment: This will be difficult ! i have no idea how you can do i, you have the headers, data types are varchar for most, and the data is stored in a random order in non delimited file ! i would put a bounty on this baby !!!!